# Cloud Firestore - Realtime listener "limit on device"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When using Cloud Firestore, it is possible to subscribe to the change/update events for the document of which mobile user is interested in.

What I wonder is: Is there a practical limit for the number of realtime data listeners for each mobile device? For an intermediate mobile device is there any limit we should not exceed?

IMHO, creating realtime data listeners on Firestore in practice corresponds to the topic subscriptions on a socket server which shouldn't have any overhead on the client-side. However, I couldn't find any documentation on this very specific issue of Firestore implementation and would like to ask for any theoretical or practical know-how you have.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287344/5861618)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes thank you for chiming in, I totally agree with the concern about premature optimization. However shouldn't total number of "triggered" listeners make up the cost? I mean if we compare, 100 listeners of which are triggered once a day and 10 listeners of which are triggered once per minute, which one do you think more expensive? This Firestore listeners don't compare with DOM listeners that's why just havind a listener shouldn't have any overhead I suppose. However, I don't have deep hands-on experience about this topic and really curious about practical know-how.